# How Titanium is helpful in developing android applications?

Tags: android, titanium

How Titanium works with android?

And it is easy to work with titanium for developing android applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know JavaScript, HTML, CSS, then you can easily create Android apps with Titanium.

Another advantage is Titanium support multi-platforms, e.g. the apps you written can also run on iPhone as well.

Comment: You don't even need to get involved with anything much other than Javascript with the current version of Titanium Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

As with any extra / higher-level layer you get portability and narrow down the API set. Also, it depends on whether you prefer Java (language and dev.toolchain) or you are accustomed to web scripting languages.